# basic variables returning all results

Tags: oracle, variables, stored-procedures, declare

I have the below variable.

```
DECLARE 
v_clt NUMBER;
BEGIN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_clt);
END;
/
SELECT *
FROM  CCP
WHERE CCP.ID = &v_clt 
--AND CASE WHEN &v_clt < 1 THEN ID ELSE &v_clt END ID
```

I have may sub-queries within my query and I would like to be able to test the query by adding in one value for each sub queries, hence the variable and it works.

I also would like to be able to return all results at any given point too. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. I don't see any subqueries either. Do you want to run a query with parameters? Say, select employees where the first and/or last name may be given or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use special value as `0` combine with [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) (or `case`) to view all results

```
WHERE CCP.ID = decode(&v_clt,0,CCP.ID,&v_clt )
```

[image]